# Why data from table is not recieving in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

When I tried to retrieve data from table it is not showing anything without giving error message.

This is my model

```
class staff(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    salary = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateField()
```

This is my views file

```
def user(request):

    staffs = staff.objects.all()
    params = {'staff': staffs}
    return render(request, "salary/user.html", params)
```

and this is my template

```
<td> 02312 </td>
{% for staff in staffs %}
    <td>{{ staff.name }} </td>
{% endfor %}
<td> $14,500 </td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
views.py

```
def user(request):
    staffs = staff.objects.all()
    return render(request, "salary/user.html", {'staff': staffs})
```

html

```
 <td> 02312 </td>
    {% for staffs in staff %}
        <td>{{ staffs.name }} </td>
    {% endfor %}
    <td> $14,500 </td>
```